# Error: Illegal Instruction

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm try to train model by Unified SSL Benchmark (USB). I have the bug: Illegal error.
I run to config: fixmatch

[Details for bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJa5D.png)

Comment: What's line 1 of `train.sh`? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running, as that will help in troubleshooting your issue. And as @waltinator notes, please be as specific as possible regarding your issue. Thanks